# How do you delete duplicate elements in htmlcollections?

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection

Im trying to delete duplicates of htmlcollections. Basically they are htmlcollection of input checkboxes with attributes `name` and `value`. I want to remove the entire `<input>` if the `name` and `value` are the same.

I couldn't find similar questions in stackoverflow. But what I have so far is to convert the htmlcollections first into array using

```
var arr = Array.from(htmlCollection);
```

and then use a `Set` to remove the duplicates, then convert it back to htmlCollection. This is way too long. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Hi, could you expand on what you mean by 'way too long' - is it the time taken? What size collection are you talking about? It could be helpful if you put up a small snippet to show what you are doing.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. What is it you are trying to achieve in a larger context.

Comment: `name`, `localName` or `tagName`?

Comment: just gotta make sure..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Just made a function `undDeal` to deal with elements that won't have a value AND OR a name

```js
let removeDuplicates=(elem)=>{
  let obj={} //for holding data for checking later
  //below function for handling elements without a name AND OR value
  //(so that <input name="undefined" value="1" /> isn't seen as <input value="1" />)
  let undDeal=(val1,val2)=>{
    if(val1==undefined){
      if(val2==undefined){return Symbol.iterator}
      return Symbol.match
    }
    return val1+val2
  }
  let elems=[...elem.children]
  let check=(el)=>{
    let specs=()=>undDeal(el.name,el.value)
    if(obj[specs()]){return true}
    obj[specs()]=1; return false
  }
  for(let i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
    if(check(elems[i])){elem.removeChild(elems[i])}
  }
}
removeDuplicates(document.body)
```

```html
<body>
<input name="asdf1" value="1" />
<input name="asdf2" value="2" />
<input name="asdf1" value="2" />
<input name="asdf2" value="2" />
<input name="asdf2" value="1" />
</body>
```